# Python Script for startswith and endswith

Tags: python, startswith, ends-with

So I made this script:

```
names = open("names.txt","r")
for loop in names:
  if loop.endswith('s'):
    print(loop)
for loop in names:
  if loop.startswth('A'):
    print(loop)
```

There was a file called `names.txt` which had 10 names in it. This program is supposed to print all the names that start with A and names that end with s but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: `endswith('s')` will never be true, because those lines have a carriage return `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple problems:

1. You've got two loops, but the file is exhausted by the first loop so the second loop never runs (it finds `names` empty and bypasses the body of the loop)
2. You're testing for `endswith('s')`, but almost every line would actually end with a newline, which you haven't stripped

As a minimal fix for both problems (maintaining the behavior of two loops so you print the lines the end with `s` separately and first):

```
with open("names.txt") as names:
    for loop in names:
        loop = loop.rstrip('\n')  # Remove trailing newline, if any, to avoid doubled
                                  # newline on print and make test work
        if loop.endswith('s'):
            print(loop)
    names.seek(0)  # Reset file pointer to beginning of file
    for loop in names:
        loop = loop.rstrip('\n')  # Same strip as in prior loop
        if loop.startswith('A'):
            print(loop)
```

If any passing line being printed on a single pass is fine, and you don't need lines beginning with `A` and ending with `s` to be printed twice, you can simplify to:

```
with open("names.txt") as names:
    for loop in names:
        loop = loop.rstrip('\n')  # Remove trailing newline, if any, to avoid doubled
                                  # newline on print and make test work
        if loop.startswith('A') or loop.endswith('s'):
            print(loop)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
def clean(names):
   return [name.strip().lower() for name in names] 

with open("names.txt", "r") as names:
   for name in clean(names):
      if name.startswith('a') and name.endswith('s'):
         print(name)
```

Keep in mind that `startswith` and `endswith` are case sensitive. Adding `lower()` in this solution makes it case insensitive. You can remove that from the `clean()` method if you want.

Also, as @ShadowRanger so graciously pointed out, you need to strip the line ending with `rstrip` (right strip). This solution uses `strip()`, which also clears any whitespace from the start of the name string, e.g. if there are tabs or spaces, they will be removed.

Comment: Thank you, guys! Your answer helped me a lot and it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it @UdayanS !